# Python grep and cut

Tags: python, cisco

In Linux, it's easy to get certain string by using tools such as grep, cut, or awk.

This `show version` sample is taken from https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst9300/software/release/16-6/configuration_guide/sys_mgmt/b_166_sys_mgmt_9300_cg/b_166_sys_mgmt_9300_cg_chapter_01.html

```
wolf@linux:~$ cat shver
cisco C9300-48P (X86) processor with 818597K/6147K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID FCW2049G03S
2048K bytes of non-volatile configuration memory.
8388608K bytes of physical memory.
1638400K bytes of Crash Files at crashinfo:.
11264000K bytes of Flash at flash:.
0K bytes of WebUI ODM Files at webui:.
Model Number                       : C9300-48P

Base Ethernet MAC Address          : 04:6c:9d:01:3b:80
Motherboard Assembly Number        : 73-17956-04
Motherboard Serial Number          : FOC20465ABU
Model Revision Number              : P4B
Motherboard Revision Number        : 04
Model Number                       : C9300-48P
System Serial Number               : FCW2049G03S

wolf@linux:~$
```

grep and cut

```
wolf@linux:~$ grep 'Model Number' shver | cut -d : -f 2
 C9300-48P
 C9300-48P
wolf@linux:~$
```

Remove extra space (If there's better solution, let me know)

```
wolf@linux:~$ grep 'Model Number' shver | cut -d : -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 2
C9300-48P
C9300-48P
wolf@linux:~$
```

Select the 1st output

```
wolf@linux:~$ grep 'Model Number' shver | cut -d : -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | head -1
C9300-48P
wolf@linux:~$
```

That was in Linux. I was planning to write similar code in Python.

My attempt which still didn't work at the moment.

Define shver string

```
>>> shver = '''cisco C9300-48P (X86) processor with 818597K/6147K bytes of memory.
... Processor board ID FCW2049G03S
... 2048K bytes of non-volatile configuration memory.
... 8388608K bytes of physical memory.
... 1638400K bytes of Crash Files at crashinfo:.
... 11264000K bytes of Flash at flash:.
... 0K bytes of WebUI ODM Files at webui:.
... Model Number                       : C9300-48P
... 
... Base Ethernet MAC Address          : 04:6c:9d:01:3b:80
... Motherboard Assembly Number        : 73-17956-04
... Motherboard Serial Number          : FOC20465ABU
... Model Revision Number              : P4B
... Motherboard Revision Number        : 04
... Model Number                       : C9300-48P
... System Serial Number               : FCW2049G03S
... '''
>>>
```

verify it

```
>>> shver
'cisco C9300-48P (X86) processor with 818597K/6147K bytes of memory.\nProcessor board ID FCW2049G03S\n2048K bytes of non-volatile configuration memory.\n8388608K bytes of physical memory.\n1638400K bytes of Crash Files at crashinfo:.\n11264000K bytes of Flash at flash:.\n0K bytes of WebUI ODM Files at webui:.\nModel Number                       : C9300-48P\n\nBase Ethernet MAC Address          : 04:6c:9d:01:3b:80\nMotherboard Assembly Number        : 73-17956-04\nMotherboard Serial Number          : FOC20465ABU\nModel Revision Number              : P4B\nMotherboard Revision Number        : 04\nModel Number                       : C9300-48P\nSystem Serial Number               : FCW2049G03S\n'
>>>
```

create a list

```
>>> shver_list = shver.splitlines()
>>> shver_list
['cisco C9300-48P (X86) processor with 818597K/6147K bytes of memory.', 'Processor board ID FCW2049G03S', '2048K bytes of non-volatile configuration memory.', '8388608K bytes of physical memory.', '1638400K bytes of Crash Files at crashinfo:.', '11264000K bytes of Flash at flash:.', '0K bytes of WebUI ODM Files at webui:.', 'Model Number                       : C9300-48P', '', 'Base Ethernet MAC Address          : 04:6c:9d:01:3b:80', 'Motherboard Assembly Number        : 73-17956-04', 'Motherboard Serial Number          : FOC20465ABU', 'Model Revision Number              : P4B', 'Motherboard Revision Number        : 04', 'Model Number                       : C9300-48P', 'System Serial Number               : FCW2049G03S']
>>>
```

Next step is to find out if string 'Model Number' is there or not and print out that line

```
>>> if 'Model Number' in shver_list:
...     'yes'
... else:
...     'no'
... 
'no'
>>>
```

How do I print out the line contains 'Model Number'?

```
>>> for i in shver_list:
...     if 'Model Number' in shver_list:
...             i
... 
>>>
```

Desired Output

```
C9300-48P
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could parse the data into a dictionary, that makes it quite easy to access the relevant informations:

```
shver = '''cisco C9300-48P (X86) processor with 818597K/6147K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID FCW2049G03S
2048K bytes of non-volatile configuration memory.
8388608K bytes of physical memory.
1638400K bytes of Crash Files at crashinfo:.
11264000K bytes of Flash at flash:.
0K bytes of WebUI ODM Files at webui:.
Model Number                       : C9300-48P

Base Ethernet MAC Address          : 04:6c:9d:01:3b:80
Motherboard Assembly Number        : 73-17956-04
Motherboard Serial Number          : FOC20465ABU
Model Revision Number              : P4B
Motherboard Revision Number        : 04
Model Number                       : C9300-48P
System Serial Number               : FCW2049G03S
'''

attributes = {}

for line in shver.splitlines():
    if ':' in line:  # we just take lines that contain a colon
        item, value = line.strip().split(':', 1)  # Split at the first colon!
        attributes[item.strip()] = value.strip()  # remove all whitespaces

print(attributes['Model Number'])
print(attributes['System Serial Number'])
```

Output:

```
C9300-48P
FCW2049G03S
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter the entries in your list. If you filter directly, you are looking for lines that are literally "Model Number".

This would print all lines that contain the substring "Model Number".

```
modelnumbers = [line for line in shver_list if 'Model Number' in line]
print(modelnumbers)`
```

To get the desired output, you use the first result, and strip away everthing not needed.

```
print(modelnumbers[0].split(":")[1].strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

From your `shver_list` step, you can do this:

```
for item in shver_list:
    if "Model Number" in item:
        break
```

So once it finds a match, it will break out the loop and look what we have in `item`:

```
>>> item
'Model Number                       : C9300-48P'
```

Now we can split this on `:` (note the spaces around) and get:

```
>>> items.split(" : ")
['Model Number                      ', 'C9300-48P']
```

So the desired element lies in the 1st positon in this list.

All in all:

```
for item in shver_list:
    if "Model Number" in item:
        break
desired = item.split(" : ")[1]
```

Another way of doing is with regular expressions. This time we take it from `shver` string:

```
import re
matches_gen = re.finditer(r"Model Number\s+:\s*(.+)", shver)
desired = next(matches_gen).group(1)
```

We use `finditer` for lazy evaluation and because we want the first occurence, we use one `next` on it and take the matching group to get the desired result of `C9300-48P`.